# Request in lambda Node.JS doesn't work timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am modifying a function in `nodejs 14` in aws lambda, The code will fetch a json and then do other tasks:

```
const https = require('https');
var http = require("https");
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');


exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('Event: ', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;



const https = require('https');
const http_get = require('https');

var options = {
    host: 'www.local.dev',
    method: 'GET',
    timeout: 2000,
    path: '/list.json',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
};



const res = await new Promise(resolve => {
  http_get.get(options, resolve);
});


let data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let data = '';
  res.on('data', chunk => data += chunk);
  res.on('error', err => reject(err));
  res.on('end', () => resolve(data));
});

data = JSON.parse(data)

// CONTINUE FUNCTION 

    return request;
};
```

I would like to set a timeout if the request to fetch the `json` doesn't return in 2 seconds., I continue the function, The function has other parts, so even if nothing comes from the json endpoint it can continue.

It has no dependency on the json return.

What is happening and that the timeout is not validated and the function is running indefinitely.

I need to use this http module from node.js, I can't use axios here.

To simulate the timeout I am using this app: [httpstat.us/501?sleep=60000](https://httpstat.us/501?sleep=60000)

Comment: Have you tried to listen to the timeout event `res.on('timeout', ... )`? [Dokumentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#event-timeout)

Comment: would be like this? ```res.on('timeout', 2000 )``` I did a test and there was an error in the function.

Comment: No the parameter should be a callback function. So you have to have timeout in your options object and register a handler if a timeout occurs.

Comment: I did some tests but it still didn't work :(

Comment: The question text seems to be exact copy of another open question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71500727/timeout-doesnt-work-for-request-made-with-node-js